# Meaning of the word "pianeta" as "augurio, acquisto, influsso"

Tags: word-meaning, history

According to [Tommaseo](http://www.tommaseobellini.it/#/doc), one of the meanings of "pianeta" is:

> 6. [Val.] Per Augurio, Acquisto, Influsso. Pucc. Centil. 77. 40. *Il Conte Ettore non diè nella rete, Perocchè alla Montagna sanza motti Per gente er'ito con miglior pianete.*

The quote is from Antonio Pucci, the XIV century. I fail to comprehend this meaning. It seems similar to 'presentiment' to me. However, this is only true for the meaning "augurio", and both "influsso" and "acquisto" do not seem to match here.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Also keep in mind that in past times _pianeta_ (or _pianeto_) also referred to the Sun and the Moon (Dante in _Inf_, I, 17, for instance use it for the Sun), and their alleged influences.

Comment: As to the Tommaseo dictionary article, _augurio_, _acquisto_ and _influsso_ are not indeed synonyms of each other, but rather possible meanings of _pianeta_ (and of course _acquisto_ doesn't mean here “something that has been bought”, but a benefit, something good to be gained from some enterprise).

Answer (score 4):

I think it refers to the following meaning by [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pianeta3/) in which *pianeta* is used metaphorically to refer to the supposed influences that planets can have over human beings according to some astrological doctrines:

> - 3 - Con riferimento alle dottrine astrologiche intorno all’influsso dei pianeti (per cui si parla spesso di p. benigno, favorevole, o avverso, maligno, e sono frequenti le espressioni nascere o essere nato sotto un buon p., un cattivo p., e sim.), sorte, destino: *è il mio pianeta che tutti m’abbiano a dare addosso* (Manzoni).

Comment: In the quote of Manzoni pianeta would be intended with the meaning of destiny, fate